# how to create environment variable in java that will use it’s value set to a comma separated list of email ids

Tags: java, jenkins

My java program outputs a list of email Ids .I need to use the Email Id to email those people through Jenkins when the java program Or that job  executes.

the most possible solution i got was creating a environment variable in java with it’s value set to a comma separated list of email ids.

But i can't figure out how to do this

Comment: So ... this would be a Jenkins task? not Java?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: Its a java Program .. which need to be integreted with jenkins  .. and after the java program executes the output would be those emails id needed to be used for emailing through jenkins

Comment: so, again: the java part you claim already to have, so you want jenkins to send mails based on your output.

Comment: yup based on the output .. for example if the   output would be                     " jacinth@gmail.com"   jenkins should  mail to that specific email id

Comment: You could write the output of your java command to a file.
Something like java -jar jar.file > output.txt
After that jenkins could read the file

Comment: @DavidMaes- even if i do that how would  jenkins read the email id's as they would be many email id's